# Carry over long sequence of missing values with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, count, null, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this:

```
create table foo (foo_label text, foo_price int, foo_date date);

insert into foo (
          values
          ('aaa', 100,  '2017-01-01'),
          ('aaa', NULL, '2017-02-01'),
          ('aaa', NULL, '2017-03-01'),
          ('aaa', NULL, '2017-04-01'),
          ('aaa', 140,  '2017-05-01'),
          ('aaa', NULL, '2017-06-01'),
          ('aaa', 180,  '2017-07-01')
        );
```

As you can see a few values on the `foo_price` column are missing.

What I need is that missing values get filled up with the "previous" available value in this way:

```
 foo_label | fixed_foo_price | foo_date
-----------+-----------------+------------
 aaa       | 100             | 2017-01-01
 aaa       | 100             | 2017-02-01
 aaa       | 100             | 2017-03-01
 aaa       | 100             | 2017-04-01
 aaa       | 140             | 2017-05-01
 aaa       | 140             | 2017-06-01
 aaa       | 180             | 2017-07-01
```

**My attempt:**

```
select 
    foo_label, 
    (case when foo_price is null then previous_foo_price else foo_price end) as fixed_foo_price,
    foo_date
from (
  select 
      foo_label, 
      lag(foo_price) OVER (PARTITION BY foo_label order by foo_date::date) as previous_foo_price, 
      foo_price,
      foo_date
      from foo
) T;
```

As you can see from here:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=s6giIonUxT

It doesn't fill completely the '100' series.

Any idea how can I get the wanted result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Form groups with the window function `count()` and then take the first value in each group:

```
SELECT foo_label
     , first_value(foo_price) OVER (PARTITION BY foo_label, grp ORDER BY foo_date) AS fixed_foo_price
     , foo_date
FROM  (
   SELECT foo_label
        , count(foo_price) OVER (PARTITION BY foo_label ORDER BY foo_date) AS grp
        , foo_price
        , foo_date
   FROM   foo
   ) sub;
```

This works because `count()` only counts non-null values. So all rows with `NULL` end up in the same group as the last row with an actual value. ***Exactly*** what you need.

Leading null values (effectively group "0") end up with `NULL`. Add a default with `COALESCE` if you want. For instance to fill in `0` instead of `NULL`:

```
     , COALESCE(first_value(foo_price) OVER (...), 0) AS fixed_foo_price
```

Answer (score 2):

### Backfill missing data in postgresql walkthrough demo

Create a table called `my_money` with an index, numeric with nulls, and a date then insert some rows.

```
drop table if exists my_money; 
CREATE TABLE my_money ( tick     character varying(10), 
                        cci_val  numeric(5,2), 
                        date_val date); 
insert into my_money values('BTC', 35.3, '2021-10-10'); 
insert into my_money values('BTC', null, '2021-10-9'); 
insert into my_money values('BTC',  9.9, '2021-10-8'); 
insert into my_money values('BTC', null, '2021-10-7'); 
insert into my_money values('BTC', null, '2021-10-6'); 
insert into my_money values('BTC',  3.0, '2021-10-5'); 
insert into my_money values('BTC', null, '2021-10-4'); 
select * from my_money;
┌──────┬─────────┬────────────┐ 
│ tick │ cci_val │  date_val  │ 
├──────┼─────────┼────────────┤ 
│ BTC  │   35.30 │ 2021-10-10 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │ 2021-10-09 │   <-- want 9.90 to fill here.
│ BTC  │    9.90 │ 2021-10-08 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │ 2021-10-07 │   <-- want 3.00 to fill here.
│ BTC  │       ¤ │ 2021-10-06 │   <-- want 3.00 to fill here.
│ BTC  │    3.00 │ 2021-10-05 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │ 2021-10-04 │   <-- want a default begin val to fill here.
└──────┴─────────┴────────────┘
```

Make a temporary table to construct our backfilled column named:  `backfilled_cci_val`

```
drop table if exists my_money2; 
CREATE TABLE my_money2 as ( 
    SELECT tick, cci_val, 
        first_value(cci_val) OVER (
        PARTITION BY tick, grp ORDER BY date_val) AS backfilled_cci_val, 
        date_val
    FROM ( 
        SELECT tick, 
        count(cci_val) OVER (PARTITION BY tick ORDER BY date_val) AS grp,
        cci_val, date_val
        FROM   my_money where tick = 'BTC'
    ) sub order by date_val desc
);
select * from my_money2;
┌──────┬─────────┬────────────────────┬────────────┐ 
│ tick │ cci_val │ backfilled_cci_val │  date_val  │ 
├──────┼─────────┼────────────────────┼────────────┤ 
│ BTC  │   35.30 │              35.30 │ 2021-10-10 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │               9.90 │ 2021-10-09 │ 
│ BTC  │    9.90 │               9.90 │ 2021-10-08 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │               3.00 │ 2021-10-07 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │               3.00 │ 2021-10-06 │ 
│ BTC  │    3.00 │               3.00 │ 2021-10-05 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │                  ¤ │ 2021-10-04 │  <-- set a default value
└──────┴─────────┴────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

So far so good but we can't backfill the first null, because there it has no prior, so you'll have to decide a default begin value manually with an update:

```
update my_money2 set backfilled_cci_val = -1 
where tick = 'BTC' 
and backfilled_cci_val is null; 
select * from my_money2; 
┌──────┬─────────┬────────────────────┬────────────┐ 
│ tick │ cci_val │ backfilled_cci_val │  date_val  │ 
├──────┼─────────┼────────────────────┼────────────┤ 
│ BTC  │   35.30 │              35.30 │ 2021-10-10 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │               9.90 │ 2021-10-09 │ 
│ BTC  │    9.90 │               9.90 │ 2021-10-08 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │               3.00 │ 2021-10-07 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │               3.00 │ 2021-10-06 │ 
│ BTC  │    3.00 │               3.00 │ 2021-10-05 │ 
│ BTC  │       ¤ │                 -1 │ 2021-10-04 │ 
└──────┴─────────┴────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Final step is to substitute the backfilled_cci_val from the new table back into cci_val from the original table:

```
update my_money set cci_val = backfilled_cci_val 
from my_money2 where my_money.date_val = my_money2.date_val; 
select * from my_money;
┌──────┬─────────┬────────────┐ 
│ tick │ cci_val │  date_val  │ 
├──────┼─────────┼────────────┤ 
│ BTC  │   35.30 │ 2021-10-10 │ 
│ BTC  │    9.90 │ 2021-10-09 │ 
│ BTC  │    9.90 │ 2021-10-08 │ 
│ BTC  │    3.00 │ 2021-10-07 │ 
│ BTC  │    3.00 │ 2021-10-06 │ 
│ BTC  │    3.00 │ 2021-10-05 │ 
│ BTC  │   -1.00 │ 2021-10-04 │ 
└──────┴─────────┴────────────┘
```

### Alternatively, if you like to live dangerously and backfill one-shot and in-place:

This update statement does the same as all the above, except does it inplace on the existing table.

```
update my_money f1 set cci_val = backfilled_cci_val from (
    SELECT tick, 
    cci_val, 
    first_value(cci_val) OVER 
        (PARTITION BY tick, grp ORDER BY date_val) AS backfilled_cci_val,
    date_val
    FROM (
        SELECT tick,
        count(cci_val) OVER (PARTITION BY tick ORDER BY date_val) AS grp,
        cci_val, date_val
        FROM   my_money where tick = 'BTC'
    ) sub order by date_val desc
) f2 where f1.date_val = f2.date_val and f1.tick = 'BTC' and f1.tick = f2.tick;
update my_money set cci_val = -1 where tick = 'BTC' and cci_val is null;
```

Which produces the same final result explained above.