# SQL (Postgres) Filling up missing rows with values from previous row and calculating on result set

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have got this dataset:

```
 id | block_number | value | name 
----+--------------+-------+------
  2 |           47 |   100 | one
  3 |           52 |   200 | one
  4 |           58 |   120 | one
  5 |           60 |   180 | one
```

created from

```
create table test (id serial, block_number int, value int, name varchar);
```

and

```
insert into test (block_number, value, name) values (47, 100, 'one'), (52, 200, 'one'), (58, 120, 'one'), (60, 180, 'one');
```

I would like to fill up the rows (not actually add them to the table but just use them for further processing), so that the column 'block_number' shows up consecutively using the value of the previous row for 'value' like so:

```
block_number | value | name 
-------------+-------+------
          47 |   100 | one
          48 |   100 | one
          49 |   100 | one
          50 |   100 | one
          51 |   100 | one
          52 |   200 | one
          53 |   200 | one
          54 |   200 | one
          55 |   200 | one
          56 |   200 | one
          57 |   200 | one
          58 |   120 | one
          59 |   120 | one
          60 |   180 | one
```

Then I would like to multiply each of these rows with a given number and sum up the total of that, for example given number would be 2 then the result of the above would be 4,240.

I haven't gotten very far with this, only thing I could come up with is a statement that generates the missing rows. However, I am failing to find out how I could set the value of each row to the one of the previous row:

```
SELECT x.block_number, x.value, t.value
           FROM (
              SELECT generate_series(min(block_number), max(block_number)) AS block_number
              FROM   my_table
               ) x
           LEFT   JOIN my_table t USING (block_number)
           ORDER  BY x.block_number;
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

#### UPDATE:

I tried to reconcile this with @mustaccio's hint here: [https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/327530/edit#:~:text=Carry%20over%20long%20sequence%20of%20missing%20values%20with%20Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/327530/edit#:%7E:text=Carry%20over%20long%20sequence%20of%20missing%20values%20with%20Postgres) and I came up with this:

```
SELECT block_number
     , first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY block_number, grp ORDER BY block_number) AS value
     
FROM  (
   SELECT 
        count(value) OVER (PARTITION BY block_number ORDER BY block_number) AS grp
        , value
        , block_number
   FROM   (
   
   SELECT x.block_number, t.value
           FROM (
              SELECT generate_series(min(block_number), max(block_number)) AS block_number
              FROM   test
               ) x
           LEFT   JOIN test t USING (block_number)
           ORDER  BY x.block_number
) test
   
   
   ) sub;
```

but it still doesn't get me the missing values:

```
 block_number | value 
--------------+-------
           47 |   100
           48 |      
           49 |      
           50 |      
           51 |      
           52 |   200
           53 |      
           54 |      
           55 |      
           56 |      
           57 |      
           58 |   120
           59 |      
           60 |   180
```

Any suggestions?

#### UPDATE 2

Thanks to @mustaccio's answer the first part is solved. I tried to amend the statement so that it does the calculation as mentioned above: Multiplying the 'value' in each row with a given number (here: 2) and then summing up all those values. What I tried:

```
SELECT SUM(a.value * 2)
FROM (

SELECT  block_number, value, first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) 
FROM (
 SELECT 
  sum(CASE WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY block_number) AS grp
  , value
  , block_number
 FROM   (
   SELECT x.block_number, t.value
   FROM (
    SELECT generate_series(min(block_number), max(block_number)) AS block_number
    FROM   test
   ) x
   LEFT   JOIN test t USING (block_number)
 ) y
) z
) a;
```

However, that gives me a result of 1,200 instead of the expected 4,060.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Carry over long sequence of missing values with Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186218/carry-over-long-sequence-of-missing-values-with-postgres)

Comment: @mustaccio I have updated my question according to the guidelines you mentioned.

Comment: Just to let you know: I tried to solve this with Google Bard and after about 20 tries it still wasn't able to come up with a working solution. Seems to be a bit tricky ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there:

```sql
SELECT  
 block_number, 
 first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY block_number) AS last_good_value
FROM (
 SELECT 
  sum(CASE WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY block_number) AS grp
  , value
  , block_number
 FROM   (
   SELECT x.block_number, t.value
   FROM (
    SELECT generate_series(min(block_number), max(block_number)) AS block_number
    FROM   test
   ) x
   LEFT   JOIN test t USING (block_number)
 ) y
) z
ORDER BY block_number
```

In order to make use of the `first_value()` function, we need to identify the group (partition) where that first value should come from. After you fill in missing `block_number`s from `generate_series`, each group comprises some non-NULL `value` followed by NULL `value`s, ordered by `block_number`; the next group begins with the next non-NULL `value`.

The `sum() OVER ...` window function calculates the sum of values from the beginning of the range to the current row, inclusive; since we don't include the `PARTITION BY` clause here, the range means the entire row set.

`CASE WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END` ensures that we only increment the sum when we encounter the next non-NULL `value`. As a result, we assign consecutive numbers (`grp`) to each group of `block_number`s.

Now that we can identify each group, we can use `first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)` to assign the "last good" value to all rows in the same `grp` partition.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AZhVEiGq)

Comment: Thanks for that, @mustaccio, first part solved then. I tried to amend your statement so that it does the calculation I mentioned in my OP: Multiplying the 'value' in each row and then summing up all those values. I updated my question accordingly, see there.

Comment: Obviously, you're multiplying the wrong column.

Comment: Yeah, that's quite obvious, but I don't know which is the right column. I tried a.value, x.value, y.value and z.value in the meantime, but to no avail. UPDATE: Ok, I missed that the column is now named 'first_value'. And now this gives me the correct result (which is not, as I wrote in my OP 4,060, but 4,240).

Comment: That's great, @mustaccio. However, would you mind explaining the core lines / strategies of your SQL a little bit? Like 'sum(CASE...' and 'PARTITION BY grp'. Pointing me to some resources where this is explained in more depth would be ok as well. I just don't feel very comfortable building on code whose beauty I cannot fully appreciate ;-)

Comment: Accepted the answer. Can you just explain to me what sum() OVER really does here? Does it calculate the number of rows in one group?