# SELECT / DELETE rows where consecutive null value count is greater than N

Tags: postgresql, delete, count, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of the following structure, where all columns except the last are non-null:

| ID | receiver | send_time | recv_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 00:00:00 | 00:00:01 |
| 2 | A | 00:00:01 | NULL |
| 3 | A | 00:00:02 | NULL |
| 4 | A | 00:00:03 | NULL |
| 5 | A | 00:00:04 | 00:00:05 |
| 6 | B | 00:00:00 | 00:00:01 |
| 7 | B | 00:00:01 | NULL |
| 8 | B | 00:00:02 | 00:00:03 |
| 9 | A | 00:00:05 | NULL |
| 10 | B | 00:00:03 | NULL |
| 11 | A | 00:00:06 | 00:00:07 |

I want to select (and ultimately delete, but I think selecting would be the first step) all rows, where the `recv_time` column is `NULL` for *n or more* consecutive rows, partitioned by the `receiver` column and ordered by the `send_time` column.

So from the above example, if *n=2*, I want to select/delete the rows with ID 2, 3 and 4, but not rows 7, 9, or 10.

I think a count with partition is needed, but I can't figure out how to "reset" the count of null values as soon as a non-null row is encountered. This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT 
    id, receiver, send_time, recv_time, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN recv_time IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY receiver ORDER BY send_time)
FROM test 
ORDER BY id
```

which gives me:

| ID | receiver | send_time | recv_time | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 00:00:00 | 00:00:01 | 0 |
| 2 | A | 00:00:01 | NULL | 1 |
| 3 | A | 00:00:02 | NULL | 2 |
| 4 | A | 00:00:03 | NULL | 3 |
| 5 | A | 00:00:04 | 00:00:05 | 3 |
| 6 | B | 00:00:00 | 00:00:01 | 0 |
| 7 | B | 00:00:01 | NULL | 1 |
| 8 | B | 00:00:02 | 00:00:03 | 1 |
| 9 | A | 00:00:05 | NULL | 4 |
| 10 | B | 00:00:03 | NULL | 2 |
| 11 | A | 00:00:06 | 00:00:07 | 4 |

But I want the count to reset at rows 5,  8, 11. I'm also not sure how I would proceed after that, because I want to capture *all* rows in the "group" of consecutive NULL rows, but obviously the count for row 2 in this example is smaller than *n*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just select:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY receiver, grp) AS grp_count
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, count(recv_time) OVER (PARTITION BY receiver ORDER BY send_time) AS grp
      FROM   test
      ) sub
   ) d
WHERE  d.grp_count > 2
AND    d.recv_time IS NULL;
```

Basically, the exact opposite of what you tried: we want the count to *stop* for rows with `null` values. Meaning, you were close, with one step in the logic inverted.

The "trick" is to do a running `count(recv_time)`. Null values don't count, so the count stalls for those rows. Candidates for removal end up in groups (`grp`) with more than 2 members for `n = 2`.

To delete:

```
DELETE FROM test t
USING (  -- same as above
   SELECT *, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY receiver, grp) AS grp_count
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, count(recv_time) OVER (PARTITION BY receiver ORDER BY send_time) AS grp
      FROM   test
      ) sub
   ) d
WHERE  d.grp_count > 2
AND    d.recv_time IS NULL
AND    t.id = d.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cQdrCICh)

Related:

- [Carry over long sequence of missing values with Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186218/carry-over-long-sequence-of-missing-values-with-postgres/186244#186244)
- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Can you clarify why you select groups where `grp_count > 3`, as opposed to where `grp_count > 2`? Keeping the example from the original question where I want to find all groups of size *equal to n or greater*. I understand each group also contains the last row where `recv_time` was not null, but still I think the correct select would be where `grp_count > n`, and not where `grp_count > n+1`.

Comment: @Edgxxar: Oh, sorry. Your understanding is impeccable. I operated under the diverging assumption `n = 3`. Adapated to `n = 2` now to make it agree with the question.